# Camera crashes: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) with JNI code

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I am currently developing an application where after the camera detected a body, an image (shirt) will be overlaid. However, after detecting the body, the camera crashes and my logcat says `Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 23908 (Thread-39833)`.

Below are the codes I've made so far.

**nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass.h** //header file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#ifndef _Included_nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass
#define _Included_nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void detectHuman(Mat& frame);
Mat putShirt(Mat frame, Point center, Size humanSize);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass_humanDetection
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass.cpp** //C++ file

```
#include "nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass_humanDetection
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong addrRgba){
    Mat& frame = *(Mat*)addrRgba;

    detectHuman(frame);
    }

  void detectHuman(Mat& frame){
    // assign xml file to a variable
    String human_cascade_name = "/storage/emulated/0/data/haarcascade_upperbody.xml";
    CascadeClassifier human_cascade;
    // load xml file
    if(!human_cascade.load( human_cascade_name ) ) { printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return; };
    std::vector<Rect> humans;
    Mat frame_gray;
    //convert input to grayscale
    cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    //increase image contrast
    equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray);
    //Detect Human
    human_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, humans, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(100, 100) );

    // Draw the mask over all rectangles
    for (size_t i = 0; i < humans.size(); i++){

        Rect r = humans[i];

        Mat humanROI = frame_gray( humans[i] ); //image of the upper body

        int h_temp = humans[i].height;    // storing original height
        int x = humans[i].x;
        int y = humans[i].y - h_temp*(-0.6); // y is increased by 0.6*h
        int w = humans[i].width;
        int h = h_temp; // height detected

        rectangle(frame, Point(x,y), Point(x + w,y +h),Scalar(255,0,255));

        Point center( humans[i].x + humans[i].width*0.5, humans[i].y + humans[i].height*0.5 );
        frame = putShirt(frame,center,Size( humans[i].width, humans[i].height));
    }
  }

  Mat putShirt(Mat frame, Point center, Size humanSize){
        Mat mask = imread("C:/Users/Requinala/AndroidStudioProjects/CLARTIPS/app/src/main/res/drawable/bluevelvet.png");
        Mat mask1,src1;
        resize(mask,mask1,humanSize);

        // ROI selection
        Rect roi(center.x - humanSize.width/2, center.y - humanSize.width/2, humanSize.width, humanSize.width);
        frame(roi).copyTo(src1);

        // to make the white region transparent
        Mat mask2,m,m1;
        cvtColor(mask1,mask2,CV_BGR2GRAY);
        threshold(mask2,mask2,230,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);

        vector<Mat> maskChannels(3),result_mask(3);
        split(mask1, maskChannels);
        bitwise_and(maskChannels[0],mask2,result_mask[0]);
        bitwise_and(maskChannels[1],mask2,result_mask[1]);
        bitwise_and(maskChannels[2],mask2,result_mask[2]);
        merge(result_mask,m );         //    imshow("m",m);

        mask2 = 255 - mask2;
        vector<Mat> srcChannels(3);
        split(src1, srcChannels);
        bitwise_and(srcChannels[0],mask2,result_mask[0]);
        bitwise_and(srcChannels[1],mask2,result_mask[1]);
        bitwise_and(srcChannels[2],mask2,result_mask[2]);
        merge(result_mask,m1 );        //    imshow("m1",m1);

        addWeighted(m,1,m1,1,0,m1);    //    imshow("m2",m1);

        m1.copyTo(frame(roi));
        return frame;
  }
```

**OpencvCamera.java** //Java class for camera

```
public class OpencvCamera extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{

    Mat mRgba;
    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        OpencvClass.humanDetection(mRgba.getNativeObjAddr());
        return mRgba;
    }
}
```

**OpencvClass.java** //java class for the jni

```
public class OpencvClass {
    public native static void humanDetection(long addrRgba);
}
```

**logcats**

```
02-24 16:45:36.269 13615-23908/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 23908 (Thread-39833)
02-24 16:45:36.372 280-280/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-24 16:45:36.372 280-280/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'CMCC/M631Y/M631Y:5.1.1/LMY47V/M631Y_02.24.00RPD_HK.00:user/release-keys'
02-24 16:45:36.372 280-280/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
02-24 16:45:36.372 280-280/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
02-24 16:45:36.373 280-280/? I/DEBUG: pid: 13615, tid: 23908, name: Thread-39833  >>> nerds.thesis.clartips <<<
02-24 16:45:36.373 280-280/? I/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
02-24 16:45:36.396 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00005d64  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
02-24 16:45:36.396 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     r4 a4674dd8  r5 00000006  r6 00000000  r7 0000010c
02-24 16:45:36.396 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     r8 00000047  r9 00000001  sl a4674400  fp 0000203e
02-24 16:45:36.397 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     ip 00005d64  sp a46732a0  lr b6dbfc2d  pc b6de5f3c  cpsr 600f0010
02-24 16:45:36.397 280-280/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
02-24 16:45:36.397 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00039f3c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
02-24 16:45:36.397 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00013c29  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
02-24 16:45:36.397 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00014847  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
02-24 16:45:36.397 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00010fd5  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
02-24 16:45:36.397 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000f534  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
02-24 16:45:36.397 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #05 pc 008a2e50  /data/app/nerds.thesis.clartips-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+344)
02-24 16:45:36.398 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0087914c  /data/app/nerds.thesis.clartips-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+4)
02-24 16:45:36.398 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0087918c  /data/app/nerds.thesis.clartips-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZSt9terminatev+16)
02-24 16:45:36.398 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00878b68  /data/app/nerds.thesis.clartips-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (__cxa_throw+168)
02-24 16:45:36.398 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #09 pc 001c8305  /data/app/nerds.thesis.clartips-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZN2cv5errorERKNS_9ExceptionE+244)
02-24 16:45:36.398 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #10 pc 001c8445  /data/app/nerds.thesis.clartips-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZN2cv5errorEiRKNS_6StringEPKcS4_i+96)
02-24 16:45:36.398 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0037660f  /data/app/nerds.thesis.clartips-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZN2cv6resizeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayENS_5Size_IiEEddi+406)
02-24 16:45:36.399 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0000fbf5  /data/app/nerds.thesis.clartips-2/lib/arm/libMyLibs.so (putShirt+172)
02-24 16:45:36.399 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0000f7ab  /data/app/nerds.thesis.clartips-2/lib/arm/libMyLibs.so (detectHuman+842)
02-24 16:45:36.399 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #14 pc 0015fc6d  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@nerds.thesis.clartips-2@base.apk@classes.dex
```

I'm a beginner and I've searched about `SIGABRT` and it says it has something to do about memory issues. I can't find where I've gone wrong in my codes.

This is very crucial. All helps/ideas will be appreciated because this will serve as my final output in college.

Comment: Did you paste the whole source code here?

Comment: I did not paste the whole code for the java class because I think they're irrelevant. Please I really need your help :(

Comment: OpenCV sends you SIGABRT when it gets something incorrect as an input (like empty image or wrong dimensions, or wrong Mat type etc)

Comment: In  your case line `02-24 16:45:36.398 280-280/? I/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0037660f  /data/app/nerds.thesis.clartips-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZN2cv6resizeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayENS_5Size_IiEEddi+406)` tells you that it crashed on cv::resize function, so my guess would be that input mask file doesn't exist

Comment: Where should I declare my input mask file then?

Comment: Well, if you run your code on android device than trying to read file from your PC (`C:/Users/Requinala/AndroidStudioProjects/CLARTIPS/app/src/main/res/drawable/bluevelvet.png`) would 100% fail, because this file is on your pc, not on your phone. Save your file on your phone and replace path with one on your phone

Comment: Oh, that should do the trick! I'll inform you if that solves my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
imread("C:/Users/Requinala/AndroidStudioProjects/CLARTIPS/app/src/main/res/drawable/bluevelvet.png")
```

tires to read the **png** from your PC disk. No wonder that it fails. You should

- always check that result of file read, etc. is OK
- read the image from your phone storage, or from assets of your app

You can use Java to extract images from the resources (or assets) to local storage, or you can use the [Android assets native API](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___asset.html) to read such images directly from the APK.

Assets seem to suit your cause better, because the drawable resources are meant to be adapted to the screen resolution.

Using native assets API with **imread()** is possible, but tricky.

Comment: Actually, I have an sqlite file inside my assets folder. This will be irrelevant to my question above but can you help me access it instead?

Comment: You should be more specific. How do you work with this sqlite? Usually, we want our database tables read/write, so unpacking it on install is the typical solution. Another trouble with updated DB tables is what to do when the app is upgraded. There is no generic shortcut to programmatic merge "from ver. 2.3.3 to ver. 3.1.4 and separately 2.3.4 to 3.1.4 and so on.

Comment: Anyway, I won't focus on that first. Your answer above helped me get away with the errors. But the input mask won't still overlay :(